# NoSuchMethodError when executing a recorded test in IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Unable to play recorded scripts on an Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0.2.

NoSuchMethodError is thrown when executing a previously recorded test, in IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench.

The same test plays out just fine on other versions of Android.

---

Following the steps described in 
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-topics/testing-mobilefirst-mobile-applications-mobile-test-workbench/
I have created my own MobileFirst project and slightly changed the index.html to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>hw</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script>
                  function count_rabbits() {
                    for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                      alert("Rabbit "+i+" out of the hat!");
                  }
              }
            </script>
            <script src="js/tracekit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/MQA.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            Hello MobileFirst
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

  <h2>Press the button to start</h2>  

    <input type="button" onclick="count_rabbits()" value="Count rabbits!"/>
</body>
</html>




        </body>
</html>
```

I built the application and deployed it on a Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0.2.
The application works as expected.

Then I create a Test Workbench project.
Using the IBM Rational Test Workbench client from my phone, I upload my application and I record myself opening it, tapping OK three times and then tapping back, then stop the recording and put it in a test.

The test shows up, I can save it and I can launch it.

Here where it goes offscript. 
[image]

It runs for a little and it fails with a:

```
An uncaught exception has been thrown in thread Thread[main,5,main]: NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/ibm/rational/test/mobile/android/runtime/webkit/WebViewClientWrapper_rtwrenamed;Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;Ljava/net/URL;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/ibm/rational/test/mobile/android/runtime/webkit/WebViewClientWrapper$1; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime.webkit.WebViewClientWrapper$1' appears in /data/app/com.myhw-1/base.apk)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime.webkit.WebViewClientWrapper_rtwrenamed.loadRemoteJavascriptsSource(WebViewClientWrapper.java:290)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime.webkit.WebViewClientWrapper_rtwrenamed.loadJavaScriptResource(WebViewClientWrapper.java:242)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime.webkit.WebViewClientWrapper_rtwrenamed.loadAndInject(WebViewClientWrapper.java:205)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime.playback.webkit.RMoTWebDriver$1.run(RMoTWebDriver.java:241)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

[image: The error screen]

What am I doing wrong?

Windows 7 64 bit with jdk 1.8.0_77

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_77
```

Luna with:

```
Android DDMS 23.0.7.2120684
Android Development Tools   23.0.7.2120684  
Android Hierarchy Viewer    23.0.7.2120684  
Android Native Development Tools    23.0.7.2120684
Android Traceview   23.0.7.2120684  
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.4.2.20150219-0708 epp.package.java    null
IBM Dojo Mobile Tools   7.1.0.00-20160321-2138
IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 7.1.0.00-20160321-2138
IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160321-2138
IBM MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7.0.v20160112_2203  
Tracer for OpenGL ES    23.0.7.2120684
```

Comment: Try with Android 4.x, does it work there?

Comment: Re-recorded the four steps on a Samsung Galaxy SIII mini with Android 4.1.2 and it worked perfectly. I even added a couple of verifications on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Uploading hybrid app to mobilefirst test workbench fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461686/uploading-hybrid-app-to-mobilefirst-test-workbench-fails)

> it is a known problem that appeared with latest build-tools versions
>
> to make short, RTW uses "dex2jar" and other utility tools, that rely
>   on android sdk.  if sdk evolve (new build-tools for example), these
>   tools have to be also ugraded (they are embedded in RTW)
>
> Best would be to upgrade RTW to latest version to be able to support
>   your sdk version (contact IBM support for that. RTW 8702 is available
>   and 871 should be live around mid october 2015)
>
> a workaround would be to to downgrade your "build-tools" in android
>   sdk manager to an older version

Comment: I am already at the latest Test Workbench. Is there a known combination RTW -- build-tools that works?

Comment: I downgraded to build-tools 19.1.0, rebuild, re-deployed, re-uploaded, re-registered and the behavior remains when we try to play the test on Android 5.0.1.

Comment: Could you please add more details to this answer. It is not that clear what I am supposed to do.